# How to set the range of input values and ground_truth values

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, caffe, torch

I am doing deep learning and my input values are a 2D images with values in range from [0, 255] and my ground_truth values are also 2D and also in range from [0, 255]. What is the most common approach to set the ranges for input and output values. I am using an EuclideanLoss in the end, and I am not sure whether my last layer should be a Convolution layer or a ReLU layer, which would also depend on the output_ground_truth range. At the moment I use [-127, 127] as input range and [0, 1] as output range with a ReLU as last layer. But I am not sure, what other people do which might be better regarding the gradients. Has someone been using input ranges from [-0.5, 0.5] and output ranges from [-0.5, -0.5] (the last layer in this case must be a convolution layer as ReLU only output positive values)

Any options, ideas, experiences?

Comment: what kind of net are using ...FCNN or segnet...for any operation like innerproduct...in most case it is followed by relu and the final ouput from the layer before loss layer(EuclidianLoss) should have the its top passed to the loss layer...

Comment: I am using a fully convolutional net, and I have found that it does not make a big difference if the last layer is a convolution layer or a ReLU layer @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: What does `the its top passed` mean? @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: I am using the stacked-hourglass network to be more specific. @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: would you mind posting your code here...i can't really guess without seing them...top is the blob passed from the previous layer to the following layer

Comment: Yeah I have got the Tensorflow code. I think you are talking about caffe. @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: That was just a general question, my last layer is a Convolution layer that means the top is an output for example of: (1, 1, 256, 256)

Comment: i am not sure if i understand your question well...but to be able calculate any loss...the output of your last layer before loss should have same value scale as the label since any prediction is the approximation of true value..thus...if you decide to use label in range[0,255] the layer before loss should produce a top that has values in that range...again...without anycode ...i can't  guess what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am asking about how to choose the labels. That is basically my question shall I use [0, 255] or [0, 1]? Or are there any good practices? @Eliethesaiyan

Comment: I think the type of  network also count.[dont know about the stackedhourglass] ..for object recognition..where you need to locate object in the images using bounding box,or location in the object..as long as the annnotation of bounding boxes has specific values...you can use the label from [0,255],for images segmentation...you can use a label that has specific pixel values..each pixel value represent a different object in image..the location where there is a car might have 1,and a place where there is  a road might be be annotated with 2.the image has only 2 value all over the image

Comment: Okay, sorry for confusing you but I am doing regression not classification. My bad!

Comment: i see..for general machine learning problem...using a value that is between [-3,3]  is recommended by Andre Young so [0,1] is better than [0.,255], for a faster convergence of a model..good luck

Comment: Ah okay, could you be more specific for input and output? My input is: [-127, 127] and output is [0, 1] @Eliethesaiyan